# Remove a Warning error (missing folder which doesn't exists anymore)

Tags: iphone, ios, warnings

[image]

I have this warning message, and I don't know how to get rid of it. I used to have a folder MBRAND3 in my folder (on the desktop) and I cleaned this folder (I moved it in another place). Then I reedited the links. All works fine, but the compiler is still looking for the former place of the folder.

Do you know what to do to clean this error message ?

Thanks

Comment: try deleting the old folder from your xcode list and when it asks whether to remove both files and their references, check remove references only. Then add the new folder again. Adding/removing links has never worked for me either :( Perhaps Apple should add documentation for this too :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to delete it from here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you still have the linking going on somewhere in your project settings

1. Try a clean-build (Clean all targets, Build)
2. Check in the project settings AND target settings if the old path is still being referenced at any location

Answer (score 0):

if the above fail, inside your xcodeproj (show package contents) - you will have a pbxproj file - try opening that in textwrangler or similar and delete any old file/folder references manually. backup first though!